# My ESP8266 01 is saying at espcomm_sync failed, espcomm_open failed, and (2x) espcomm_upload_mem failed. OS X

Tags: arduino-uno, esp8266, mac-os, osx

I'm extremely frustrated at my ESP8266 right now, with the Arduino. I am using a 6v DC battery power supply (4xAA batteries), and a 3.3v voltage regulator (NTE1904). I have the connections as shown:

- Vcc - 3.3v rail
- CH_PD - 3.3v rail
- RST - 3.3v rail (I put it into GND when I need to reset)
- GPIO 0 - GND (I momentarily put the reset in ground after)
- TXD - Rx
- RXD - Tx

I have the 6V from the 4xAA batteries into the Vin of the 3.3V voltage reulgator, it's ground to the ground of batteries (and therefore connected to Arduino), and the output connected to the 3.3v rail.

I had the circuit working before, and I had it not receiving a packet header, but when I resembled the circuit fully I am now getting these errors when uploading my code:

`Sketch uses 232778 bytes (53%) of program storage space. Maximum is 434160 bytes.
Global variables use 31981 bytes (39%) of dynamic memory, leaving 49939 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 81920 bytes.
warning: espcomm_sync failed
error: espcomm_open failed
error: espcomm_upload_mem failed
error: espcomm_upload_mem failed`

I've tried a bunch, and I am not sure where my problem is. Note:

- I have changed my platform.txt (*Arduino15/packages/.../esp8266/2.2.0/platform.txt*)'s `tools.esptool.upload.pattern` to: `tools.esptool.upload.pattern="{path}/{cmd}" {upload.verbose} -cd {upload.resetmethod} -cb {upload.speed} -cp "{serial.port}" -ca 0x00000 -cf "{build.path}/{build.project_name}.bin"` *(or have I? It seems quite unorganized I've changed it in the past from a tutorial saying that esptool doesn't work properly on OS X, but the page is quite hard to locate again. Please tell me what you use currently)*

Again, I am on OS X (10.11.4)

Thank you for any help. It is extremely frustrating trying to get this, and I cannot seem to find any up-to-date tutorials with my problem. If you know anything I could try, that would be great.

Comment: Can you describe in better detail what hardware you're using? I am not clear on if you're using a single ESP 8266 board acting as the CPU, or some sort of other microcontroller on a board (e.g., an Arduino Uno) with a separate pre-programmed ESP 8266 board acting as a peripheral. Links to datasheets or product pages for your exact hardware are best. Also, if you can provide a schematic of some sort so we can see exactly what pins are connected to what, that will be a lot more clear than your textual description.

Comment: don't ground gpio0

Comment: Depending on you hardware you might need level shifters on the serial lines (both of them)

Comment: any luck after un-grounding? if not, please post more wiring details.